# Hall Effect and Magnetoresistors

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism

As per my understanding, When an electric field is applied to a current carrying wire, it exerts Lorentz force on electrons and hence a transverse electric field is generated. Also when we apply magnetic field wire resistance changes called as magnetoresistive effect.
  My Question is aren't both of these effects are same? Or am i making some mistake. Also i found somewhere that magnetoresistive effect is of 2nd order while Hall effect is 1st order.How is this possible if both have same cause.
(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Oops, magnetic field supplies Lorentz force q(vxB)  (where the x is the vector cross product.)  Hall effect gives a voltage perpendicular to electron velocity, magnetio-resistance is parallel.  A voltage drop along the device.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Hall Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) and [magnetoresistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance) are very different effects.

In particular, [giant magnetoresistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance) is a quantum effect that has been widely exploited to implement magnetometors (electronic compasses), disk drive read heads, biosensors, and [MRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistive_random-access_memory).